# JSON-RPC with Golang. Electrumx error: Invalid scripthash

Tags: go, json-rpc

Tell me please where is my mistake

i try get balance use this method https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-methods.html?highlight=balance#blockchain-scripthash-get-balance

i get scripthash from docs https://electrumx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/protocol-basics.html#script-hashes
and send to electrum

but electrumx return error `invalid error map[code:1 message:Invalid scripthash] exit status 1`

my code

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/rpc/jsonrpc"
)

func main() {
    rpcClient, err := jsonrpc.Dial("tcp", "de.poiuty.com:50001")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    scripthash := "8b01df4e368ea28f8dc0423bcf7a4923e3a12d307c875e47a0cfbf90b5c39161"
    err = rpcClient.Call("blockchain.scripthash.get_balance", `{"scripthash":"`+scripthash+`"}`, "")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a guess but it looks like you are missing a quote (`"scripthash":8b...` should be `"scripthash": "8b...`) [example](https://go.dev/play/p/TI5W67sAAoj).

Comment: @Brits thanks, i add fix in my code, but electrum return same error